# How to have refences in c# as function arguments

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass references as arguments in a method in  c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007596/how-to-pass-references-as-arguments-in-a-method-in-c)
>
> Duplicate: [How to pass references as arguments in a method in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007596/how-to-pass-references-as-arguments-in-a-method-in-c)

How to pass the references in C# as parameters like c ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007596/how-to-pass-references-as-arguments-in-a-method-in-c

Answer (score 5):

You can read a great article on parameter passing on [Jon Skeet's website](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html). I encourage you to read the entire thing, it isn't very long. It has great explanations and examples. There is also a link there to [this site](http://rapidapplicationdevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/01/parameter-passing-in-c.html) which breaks it down with some pictures.

Comment: Jon did a very good write up on this.  This article should be a requirement for any C# developer to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ref keyword, or the out keyword.

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7(VS.71).aspx

Out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example :

```
void addition(int a, int b, out int result, ref int count)
{
  result = a + b;
  count ++;
}

void static main()
{
  int opCount = 0;  // need initialization
  int opResult;     // don't need initialization

  addition(5, 4, out opResult, ref opCount);
  Console.WriteLine("5 + 4 = {0}", opResult); // display "5 + 4 = 9"

  addition(2, 3, out opResult, ref opCount);
  Console.WriteLine("2 + 3 = {0}", opResult); // display "2 + 3 = 5"

  Console.WriteLine("Operation count : {0}", opCount); // display "Operation count : 2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can use the ref keyword to pass parameters by reference or you can use the out keyword to pass a parameter as an output.

See the MSDN documentation on:
[ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)
[out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx)